# Jersey 2.9 and Jackson 1.x as JSON provider

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0

I have a dependency to the third-party library Woorea Openstack-SDK (https://github.com/woorea/openstack-java-sdk) which uses Jackson 1.x annotations. Because of the Jackson update (Jackson 1.x -> Jackson 2.x) in Jersey 2.9, the Openstack-SDK becomes incompatible.

Is there a way to use Jersey 2.9 together with Jackson 1.x as JSON provider?

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/ to provide Jackson 2.x to previous versions of Jersey (wihtout Jackson 2.x support). Should be an alternative to provide now Jackson 1.x to new versions of Jersey(with Jackson 2.0 support). Otherwise, check the implementation in the above link. You could do the same, since it's mostly about registering a new provider.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... I removed the dependency to the artifact `jersey-media-json-jackson` and registered the following feature:

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;

import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper;
import org.glassfish.jersey.CommonProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.InternalProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper;

public class Jackson1xFeature implements Feature {

private final static String JSON_FEATURE = Jackson1xFeature.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public boolean configure(final FeatureContext context) {
    final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();

    final String jsonFeature = CommonProperties.getValue(config.getProperties(), config.getRuntimeType(), InternalProperties.JSON_FEATURE, JSON_FEATURE, String.class);
    // Other JSON providers registered.
    if (!JSON_FEATURE.equalsIgnoreCase(jsonFeature)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Disable other JSON providers.
    context.property(PropertiesHelper.getPropertyNameForRuntime(InternalProperties.JSON_FEATURE, config.getRuntimeType()), JSON_FEATURE);

    // Register Jackson.
    if (!config.isRegistered(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class)) {
        // add the default Jackson exception mappers
        context.register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class);
        context.register(JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class);
        context.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class, MessageBodyReader.class, MessageBodyWriter.class);
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Found myself solving the exact same problem.
Jackson1 provider is available in jersey-media-json-jackson1 maven artifact. Instead of writing the provider in project, use/register the provider available in maven artifact (Provider name: Jackson1Feature).